# ASP.NET MVC5: Directly view the .cshtml file in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new in ASP.NET MVC, I am trying to open **Navbar.cshtml** in browser directly. After a lots of efforts and seeing results I am not able to open it directly. It is showing me same errors after testing many results.

[image]

My **Navbar.cshtml** file is in **view folder** directory.

**Navbar.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Navbar";
}

<h2>Navbar</h2>
```

Comment: You have any controller action associated with the view?

Comment: A cshtml requires a controller to view it in browser, it can't be accessed directly unlike ASPX page does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have to create a controller action associate with that view.

In your controller,create an action method like this

```
 public ActionResult Navbar()
    {
       //do something
    }
```

Right click on actionname Navbar,add view Navbar.cshtml. Then run your cshtml file.

Comment: @NabiaSaroosh Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Like others have stated, you won't be able to view .cshtml files directly and need a controller to handle it. Doing something like [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/daf0357dfac1db074a60d9b87c3b3cc5) should help you view your desired Navbar.cshtml.

If possible, you should also set the correct startup file in the Startup.cs file.

Comment: Your answer is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the solution you are looking . Lets say your Navbar.cshtml file is located under Shared folder

```
View("~/Views/Shared/Navbar.cshtml");
```

And also you have to call all view from a controller.